# Create Primary Fields based on total sum individually in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for guidance on how to achieve primary field(s) based on a summed total independently.

I have a dataset that is at a monthly grain, with an account id, consumption, date field, platform, type, and type_2. I want to create three new fields (primary platform, type, and type_2) based on the total consumption per account id. I do not want these fields to be derived based on the combination of the three, I want each field to look at the consumption totals independently per account. The final set would return one record per account, with those three fields and the value which represented the most dollars.

I'd also like to create the same three fields, but now based on secondary (what ever the second most running in dollars for platform, type, and type_2 as well).

I could do something like this, but this is very repetitive and then will just be more work when joining all the data back together.

```
variable_1 <- my_data %>%
  group_by(accountID, platform) %>%
  summarize(total_consumption = sum(dollars)
```

```
final_variable_1 <- variable_1 %>% 
  group_by(accountID) %>%
  filter(total_consumption == max(total_consumption)) %>%
  select(accountID, platform) %>%
  rename(primary_platform = platform)
```

I had this, but it does not seem to work using Databricks:

```
my_dataset %>%
  group_by(accountID) %>%
  summarize(
    primary_platform = platform[which.max(dollars)],
    primary_type = type[which.max(dollars)],
    primary_type_2 = type_2[which.max(dollars)]
  )
```

Comment: Need `dput(head(my_dataset))` and a better description of the meaning of “does not work”.

Comment: Does not work- getting an error about catalog (which has nothing to do with this), that is properly defined when I read in the variables.

Comment: So is the response to the first bit of missing information (the missing dataset example)  or the second part (the request for meaning of "doesn't work"). You are probably working with a dataset created by a package that you have not told us about. `sessionInfo()` would demonstrate what packages are currently in the workspace. I'm now going to vote for closure based on "needs detail".

Comment: Apologize on the slow response. I can't provide the dataset directly as it's non sharable data. I did come up with a solution to achieve what I want. It's a little long so I can't post in this comments section. If you reply to the question I can up there.